# jQuery: Loading selection after selection with AJAX

Tags: jquery, html, select

Live example at http://alkitab.me/ (it's an Indonesian Bible website to give you some context)

If you try clicking on the first dropdown, the second `<select>` will get its option based on your first selection, then the third based on your second. It's already working, but I'm wondering if there's a better way than doing AJAX? **As it doesn't actually work on windows mobile 6.x browser as well as opera mini.**

On Windows Mobile, the second selection just doesn't appear after selecting one, and on Opera Mini, after choosing the first option, the whole page simply reloads.

Someone actually mentioned using iframe instead of AJAX, is that actually better?

Thanks for any idea!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I used text field and give a range of verse users can put in based on their book selection.